# Proving that a function of a Brownian Motion is a martingale

Tags: calculus

$(B_t)$ is a Brownian Motion (t is positive).
I want to prove that $ exp(B_t - t/2) $ is a martingale.
I tried going back to the definition and prove the formula with the condition expectation but I didn't succeed.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

For any $s<t$ you know the conditional distribution of $B_t$ given $\mathcal{F}_s$ is normal with mean $B_s$ and variance $t-s,$ so you just need to compute the average value of $e^{B_t}$ under this distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(t,x) = e^{x-\frac{1}{2}t}.$$

By Itô's lemma, the drift of $\mathrm{d}f(t,B_t)$ is given by

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = -\frac{1}{2}f+\frac{1}{2} f = 0. $$

Hence, $f(t,B_t)$ is an Itô process with no drift, and therefore a martingale.